# Why do some solutions of the Schrodinger's equation emerge un-normalized? It goes against logic

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

Why do some solutions of the Schrodinger equation emerge un-normalized? Logically, any solution psi must have its integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\varphi|^2\, dx = 1$ because the probability has to certain across all x. Hence any solution that comes out of solving the SWE must be normalized. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think some examples are in order. You need to specify what exactly you mean by "why do some solutions...emergy un-normalized?". Solutions to the Schroedinger equation involve unitary time-evolution and so normalization will be preserved in time. This has been proven. See e.g. http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~tbrun/Course/lecture05.pdf for a quick and simple proof.

Comment: @enumaris IIRC the time-independent equation has non-normalizable solutions in (for example) the harmonic oscillator potential, to take a nontrivial example.

Comment: @Javier I took the question to mean that the OP thinks that some wave functions which were normalized become unnormalized due to time-evolution through the TDSE. This is due to my interpretation of his statement "emerge un-normalized" which suggests to me some sort of evolution (emerge). Perhaps the OP can clarify this point better.

Comment: What about solutions involving free particles?

Comment: @enumaris My choice of words might have made my question ambiguous. By "emerge un-normalized", I meant the solutions to a TISE under some potential may not satisfy the given integral. We often multiply the solution with 'A' (since SE is linear) and find the expression for this. (Eg- Harmonic Oscillator or particle in an infinite square well). Hence my query is that if the TISE is true, the solutions drawn from it for a particle under some potential must satisfy the integral without finding out any 'A'.

Comment: @SameerDambal An analogy: In introductory mechanics, you often have problems like: "You throw a ball upwards at t=0 with initial velocity v=1 m/s and initial height 1.5 m. When does the ball hit the ground?" If you just write out the equations of motion and solve for t, you get two solutions: one positive, one negative. You then have to *separately insert physical reasonableness* by saying the ball must hit at a positive time. Similarly, when you solve TISE, you get a bunch of solutions. You have to *separately* demand that you want the normalized one. The math doesn't determine everything.

Comment: @JahanClaes The negative time in that classical mechanics examples corresponds to the scenario where the ball would have supposedly started before arriving at its given-initial position (1.5m). The math does give out all the possible scenarios of results if the initial conditions are incorporated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> Logically, any solution $\psi$ must have its integral
>   $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\phi|^2dx=1$ because the probability has to
>   certain across all x

This simply isn't true for the reason that not all solutions to Schrodinger's equation (SE) correspond to a physical state.  Put another way, only normalizable solutions to SE correspond to physical states.

For example, there are an uncountable infinity of solutions to the quantum harmonic oscillator SE *but* there are only a countable infinity of solutions that are normalizable and thus are representations of physical states.

It *is* logical that any solution $\psi$ to the SE that is a representation of a physical state is normalizable but it certainly *is not* logical that any solution to a partial differential equation such as the SE is normalizable.

Answer (score 1):

What solutions are you referring to? If you're referring to solutions of the *time-independent Schrodinger equation*, e.g. the eigenfunctions, then these can be normalizable or not depending on your potential $V$. However, in general these solutions have *nothing to do* with the wavefunction of the actual particle. The wavefunction of an *actual particle* is always normalized, as you say. But the eigenfunctions don't need to be normalizable, because the eigenfunctions don't necessarily represent a physical state of a particle. They simply represent a convenient basis for expanding physical wavefunctions.

For more about this distinction, see the section in Griffiths, chapter 2, where he discusses constructing the wavefunction of a free particle.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Schrödinger equation is linear it does not fix the norm of its solutions. You have to do that manually at your desk.